# How to check the signature without the predetermined function in ECDSA from openssl?

Tags: signature, dsa, openssl

I'm developing a client for a two-factor authentication in Qt/C++ under openSUSE 13.2, 64bit. I've got the FIDO U2F Security Key from [yubico/fido](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/fido-u2f-security-key/).
I'm using the classes from openssl, in particular `ecdsa.h` and `bn.h`.

The registration went smoothly, so I can get the $r$ and $s $from the signature. I can also check whether the point lies on the curve (so I've got the public key, too).

My actual problem is to verify the signature. I have to use the curve P-256 from NIST. I've tried it with `ECDSA_verify` and `ECDSA_do_verify`, but I don't know how to set my public key. Also, I think I will not get the private key. So, I think that this methods are not useful for me. Therefore I want to develop own methods to verify my signature. I've studied the ECDSA algorithm, but I don't know where I should begin. I know what to do, but I'm unsure how to implement in my program.

I'd be very glad if anyone has an idea which could help me. 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This question (and [your followup](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30809/how-to-verify-a-signature-with-openssl-methods-from-the-ecdsa-class)) might be better suited for [so]. Crypto.SE is really more for the theoretical side of cryptography (i.e. we'd be happy to explain how ECDSA works, but "how to use OpenSSL" is getting a bit off topic). You may want to see our [help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information about our scope.